# Get lengths of a list in a jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

How do I get the number of elements in a list in jinja2 template?

For example, in Python:

```
print(template.render(products=[???]))
```

and in jinja2

```
<span>You have {{what goes here?}} products</span>
```

Answer (score 821, accepted):

```
<span>You have {{products|length}} products</span>
```

You can also use this syntax in expressions like

```
{% if products|length > 1 %}
```

jinja2's builtin filters are documented [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters); and specifically, as you've already found, [`length`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#length) (and its synonym `count`) is documented to:

> Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.

So, again as you've found, `{{products|count}}` (or equivalently `{{products|length}}`) in your template will give the "number of products" ("length of list")

Comment: Can we check for undefined too? I have to use {% if products is none ... %} which is quite tiring

Comment: @wvxvw this does work: `{% set item_count = items | length %}` as long as `items` is a list, dict, etc.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMartelli. In addition we could use inline syntax like `{{ form.select_field(size=5 if form.select_field.choices|count > 5 else form.select_field.choices|count) }}`

Answer (score 16):

Alex' comment looks good but I was still confused with using range.
The following worked for me while working on a for condition using length within range.

```
{% for i in range(0,(nums['list_users_response']['list_users_result']['users'])| length) %}
<li>    {{ nums['list_users_response']['list_users_result']['users'][i]['user_name'] }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can loop through your collection in pythonic way: ```{% for user in nums['list_users_response']['list_users_result']['users'] %} <li>{{ user['user_name'] }} </li>
{% endfor %}```

Answer (score 7):

I've experienced a problem with length of None, which leads to Internal Server Error: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

My workaround is just displaying 0 if object is None and calculate length of other types, like list in my case:

```py
{{'0' if linked_contacts == None else linked_contacts|length}}
```

Comment: You could use **none** build-in function to test for _None_. Check more here: [https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#none](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#none). Example is on this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614027/jinja2-template-variable-if-none-object-set-a-default-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614027/jinja2-template-variable-if-none-object-set-a-default-value)

Answer (score 6):

If for loop with array is used then you can use the following

```
{% for i in range(array|length) %}
          array[i]
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<span>You have {% for n in products %}{% if loop.index == 1 %}{{ loop.length }}{% endif %}{% endfor %} products</span>
```