# Check if an array is not empty in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I need to check if the variable `texts` is defined or not in `index.html`.

If the variable is defined and not empty then I should render the loop. Otherwise, I want to show the error message `{{error}}`.

Basically this in PHP

```
if (isset($texts) && !empty($texts)) {
    for () { ... }
}
else {
    print $error;
}
```

**index.html**

```
{% for text in texts %} 
    <div>{{error}}</div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-title">{{text.subject}}</div>
        <pre class="post-content">{{text.content}}</pre>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I say this in jinja2?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of Jinja2 `defined()`: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#defined

```
{% if variable is defined %}
    value of variable: {{ variable }}
{% else %}
    variable is not defined
{% endif %}
```

Is it clear enough? In your case it could look like this:

```
{% if texts is defined %}
    {% for text in texts %} 
        <div>{{ error }}</div>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-title">{{ text.subject }}</div>
            <pre class="post-content">{{ text.content }}</pre>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    Error!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This misses the edge case of a defined array that is empty, which should also be an error, according to the original question.

Comment: @Andrew Do you know how to fix this edge case?

Comment: @PatrickMutuku Case of empty but defined array can be handled by  {% if texts %}

Answer (score 75):

I think your best bet is a combination of defined() check along with looking at the [length of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465249/jinja2-get-lengths-of-list) via [length() function](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length):

```
{% if texts is defined and texts|length > 0 %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `texts|length > 0` is equivalent to `texts` -- an empty list in a boolean test evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 58):

To test for presence ("defined-ness"?), use `is defined`.

To test that a present list is not empty, use the list itself as the condition.

While it doesn't seem to apply to your example, this form of the emptiness check is useful *if you need something other than a loop*.

An artificial example might be

```
{% if (texts is defined) and texts %}
    The first text is {{ texts[0] }}
{% else %}
    Error!
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for), you could also write:

```
{% for text in texts %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-title">{{text.subject}}</div>
        <pre class="post-content">{{text.content}}</pre>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div>{{ error }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It handles both the case where `texts` is undefined, and the case where `texts` is empty.

Answer (score 8):

This is a neat and simple solution that worked well for me!

```
{% if texts is defined and texts[0] is defined %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that `texts` could be defined but contain a single list element which is an empty string; For example:

```
texts = ['']
```

In this case, testing if `texts` is defined will produce a true result so you should test the first element instead:

```
{% if texts[0] != '' %}
    ..code here..
{% endif %}
```

You might also want to combine that with the `|length` filter to make sure it only has one element.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ( But I make sure to return an empty array [] and not None if its empty )

```
{% if array  %}

   <table class="table">
       ...
   </table>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when working with the UPS API where if there is only one object in a parent object the child is just an object, but when there is more than one child it's a array of objects.

```
{% if texts[0] %}
    ..code here..
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for my use case in my Django app:

I needed to pass a queryset as context to an html template and display the block only if the queryset had values

Queryset:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(schedule_end__gte=date.today()).order_by('-created_at')
```

Passed context dictionary as follows:

```
{ "events" : events }
```

HTML template

```
{% if events %}
  <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for event in events %}
    <li><h4>{{ event.title }}</h4></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check if array is not empty by writing below jinja code.
where the content2 is an array defined under py file. `@app.route("/<name>") def home(name): return render_template("index.html", content=name, content2=[])`

```
{% if content2 %}
<div>
    <h2>Array elements are available</h2>
    {% for con2 in content2 %}
        <p> {{con2}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks