# How do I display a message in Jinja (flask) if there is no object data to display

Tags: html, python-3.x, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an object in python `views.py` that references the `events` database table.  When there is data, it displays the data in my html template, however, when there is no data, I cannot figure out the `{% if %}` function that would display the message "No data found."

I have tried [Tadeck's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503981/check-if-an-array-is-not-empty-in-jinja2), but the `is defined` always seems to evaluate to true even if there is no data to display.  Thank you for your help.

```
{% if events is defined %}
    value of variable: {{ events }}
{% else %}
    variable is not defined
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
events = db.session.query(Eventdetails, Buyers).\
            join(Buyers).\
            filter(Eventdetails.events_id == event_id)

return render_template(
            self.template_file, events=events, the_event=the_event,
            event_id=event_id
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `events` as the query.  You want it to be the query results:

```
events = db.session.query(Eventdetails, Buyers).\
        join(Buyers).\
        filter(Eventdetails.events_id == event_id).all()
```

Things to try:

```
{% if events %}
{% if events|length > 0 %} 
{% if events != [] %}
```

Comment: This has been helpful, but unfortunately, neither really worked.

{% if events %} always evaluated to True, never showing the else message

{% if events|length > 0 %} throws an error BaseQuery' has no len()

{% if events != [] %} always evaluated to true, never showing the else message

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. When event have data then it will go inside the if condition otherwise else will be execute `No data found`.

```
{% if events %}
    value of variable: {{ events }}
{% else %}
    No data found.
{% endif %}
```