# How do you display model attribute in a table within am html file?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a project and a task model and I want to make a table in a detail html that displays the tasks in the project.

I've tried doing

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Assignee</th>
         <th>Start Date</th>
         <th>Due Date</th>
         <th>Is compeleted</th>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
         <td>{{ task.name }} </td>
         <td>{{ task.assignee }}</td>
         <td>{{ task.start_date }}</td>
         <td>{{ task.due_date }}</td>
         <td>{{ task.is_completed }}</d>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

but it just shows the table headers and not its content

here is my task model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        "projects.Project",
        related_name="tasks",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        related_name="tasks",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("show_my_tasks")
```

Comment: where is `view.py` with code which renders template? Did you send task to this template?

Answer (score 0):

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72738106/15978450) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72737747/15978450) had something like:

```
{% for project in projects_list %}
     ...

     {% if project.tasks.count > 0 %}
          # Displaying the table in here with the project's task info...
     {% else %}
          <p> no tasks for this project </p>
     {% endif %}

     ...
{% endfor %}
```

You should loop over all the project's tasks `set` within the table. For example:

```
# Within the true portion of the if statement...
{% if project.tasks.count > 0 %}
     # Displaying the table in here with the project's task info...

     <table>
          <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Assignee</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                    <th>Is compeleted</th>
               </tr> 
          </thead>
  
          <tbody>
               # The set of related tasks for the current project -> project.tasks.all
               {% for task in project.tasks.all %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{ task.name }} </td>
                         <td>{{ task.assignee }}</td>
                         <td>{{ task.start_date }}</td>
                         <td>{{ task.due_date }}</td>
                         <td>{{ task.is_completed }}</d>
                    </tr> 
              {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
    </table>
{% else %}
     <p> no tasks for this project </p>
{% endif %}
```