# Python jinja2 template, how to count a list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

So I can't use python len() for a list in the templates like below.

```
{% if len(alist) == 0 %}

UndefinedError: 'len' is undefined
```

1. How can we use python in the templates?
2. Is passing a param to the template in the def get(self) method the only way to do this?
3. Anyone know some good resources on how to use jinja2 with it comes to templating? like what methods can you use and the syntactic difference between python and jinja2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you do a quick search in the [template documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) you will quite soon find the [`length`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#length) filter.

As for the rest, read the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/).

Comment: For quick reference: {% if alist|length == 0 %}

Comment: -1 cause you could have saved us your remark implying the person asking the question being too lazy to search the docs. Some things you dont find as easy if you don't know exactly what to search for. And IMHO it's the responsiblity of Jinja's authors to create a template language that looks like being "normal" python, but in certain corner cases isn't, and then throwing pretty unclear error messages. Thanks for the 1/4 helpful part of your answer ;)

Comment: Since when was 'RTFM' considered an acceptable or helpful answer?

Answer (score 31):

```
{% if alist |length ==0 %}  or  {% if alist |count ==0 %}
```

i Solve it with that way!!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if alist.count() == 0 %}
```

That should solve your problem.

You can [check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465249/jinja2-get-lengths-of-list).

Comment: i am getting following error 
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: `count()` counts a specific item. I don't think this works, please correct if required.