# Traversing SQLAlchemy relationships - determining users that liked a post

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am rather new to flask and sql-alchemy. I am having trouble with relationships between different models. Specifically, I am trying to print to the front-end HTML the usernames of the users that liked a specific post.

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', primaryjoin="User.id==Post.author_id")
    ...


    liked = db.relationship(
        'PostLike',
        foreign_keys='PostLike.user_id',
        backref='user', lazy='dynamic')


    def like_post(self, post):
        if not self.has_liked_post(post):
            like = PostLike(user_id=self.id, post_id=post.id)
            db.session.add(like)

    def unlike_post(self, post):
        if self.has_liked_post(post):
            PostLike.query.filter_by(
                user_id=self.id,
                post_id=post.id).delete()

    def has_liked_post(self, post):
        return PostLike.query.filter(
            PostLike.user_id == self.id,
            PostLike.post_id == post.id).count() > 0


class PostLike(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post_like'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    likes = db.relationship('PostLike', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
    ...
```

In my flask application, when printing out posts, I want to be able to display the usernames of the likers of the post. I have been able to get the like function to work and display the number of likes, through:

```
{{ post.likes.count() }}
```

through jinja2 in the HTML front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `post_like` table is just a simple pairing of two rows in different tables, you can use a secondary relationship to reach through that directly to the user object.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    likes = db.relationship('User', secondary='post_like',
                            backref=db.backref('post', lazy='dynamic'))
```

If you wanted to add more columns to the secondary table, then you'll have to use the more-complex [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) pattern.

Also, you shouldn't have two `posts` relationships, they need to be merged.

Comment: Thanks, it does display the usernames. However, how would I display the number of likers? `{{ post.likes.count() }}` returns this error `TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`. On the other hand, `{{ post.likes.count }}` returns the object `<built-in method count of InstrumentedList object at 0x000001853C484958>` in the HTML page.

Comment: You need to [do that in Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465249/get-lengths-of-a-list-in-a-jinja2-template#1466550).