# How to aceess list item in jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I have 2 list in my `Django` site.

my `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    totalDBElement = [169, 2166, 5413, 635, 635]
    elementOrder = ['Rules', 'Questions', 'ParentChild', 'ChildList']
    return render(request,'diagnosis/index.html', {'totalDBElement': totalDBElement, 'elementOrder' : elementOrder})
```

I wish to get something like this in my `template:`

> ### Rules: 169
>
> ### Questions: 2166
>
> ### ParentChild:
> 5413
>
> ### ChildList: 635

my `template`:

```
{% for i in len(totalDBElement) %}
<h2> {{ totalDBElement[i] }} </h2>
<h2> {{ elementOrder[i] }} </h2>
{% endfor %}
```

But it gives errors like:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(totalDBElement)' from 'len(totalDBElement)'
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

I also wish to print

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466550/15792008 use |count instead of len()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index(request):
    totalDBElement = [169, 2166, 5413, 635, 635]
    elementOrder = ['Rules', 'Questions', 'ParentChild', 'ChildList']
    all_in_one = zip(elementOrder,totalDBElement)
    return render(request,'diagnosis/index.html', {'totalDBElement':all_in_one})
```

now in template

```
{% for item1, item2 in totalDBElement %}
<h2> {{ item1 }}:{{ item2 }} </h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: just a small change.... `all_in_one` in place of `totalDBElement` inside the jinja